# initWithCoder error when loading custom CollectionViewCell Nib

Tags: swift

I am creating a custom `UICollectionViewCell` in a `.xib` file with the below code but am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

All of the other Stack Overflow solutions are with Objective C, so am very confused of what to do. In my NIB file, the class is set in the identity controller and so is the reusable identifier.

The `UICollectionViewCell` I am using is from an API called `Gemini`, hence why the cell is called `GeminiCell`. However `Gemini` isn't the issue as it works without using the NIB.

**cellForItemAtIndexPath in View Controller**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Doesn't work
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlbumsCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! AlbumsCell

    // Also doesn't work
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsCell

    return cell
}
```

**Custom Cell class**

```
class AlbumsCell: GeminiCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var albumsImageView:UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cell needs to implement required init. Just write `required init` in your cell class and you’ll see the autocomplete

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla I've updated my code to the code in my answer. This still returns the error

Comment: Should be like this: `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }` or anything you want in the fatal error description

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla This still doesn't work

Comment: Is the cell in storyboard or programmatically? If programmatically or nib you need to register it as well. Check the documentation. It should always be the first step to solve problems: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla It's all programmatic. And I registered it in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Don't really know what the problem is without seeing all the code. But have a look at my answer. Probably it can guide you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cell with programmatically then you need to write init with coder the reason anybody can use your cell by using storyboard then that init with coder will call not init with frame call that’s why you need to implement this initializer